# I don't seem to understand why this function call is incorrect

Tags: c

The code below, when runs gives me two warnings, which are as follows:

```
kwoc3.c:161:14: warning: implicit declaration of function 'remove_item' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                                *words = remove_item(*words, curr->text);
                                         ^
kwoc3.c:161:12: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'node_t *'
      (aka 'struct node_t *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
                                *words = remove_item(*words, curr->text);
                                       ^
```

I dont seem to understand why it says this.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "emalloc.h"
#include "listy.h"

#define MAX_LINE_LEN 100
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 40

typedef struct Lines_and_Words Lines_and_Words;
struct Lines_and_Words{
    char array_lines[MAX_LINE_LEN];
};

struct Ntab{
    Lines_and_Words *lines;
    int max_elements;
    int index;
};

enum{
    NINIT = 8,
    NGROW = 2
};

void command_line_input(int argc, char *argv[], char **input_file, char **exp_filename);
void read_file_in_array(char *filename, struct Ntab *ntab);
int add_line(char *line, struct Ntab *ntab);
void store_words(struct Ntab *ntab, node_t **words, int *word_counter);
void remove_exceptions(node_t **words, node_t **exp_words, int *word_counter);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *filename = NULL;
    struct Ntab ntab_lines;
    ntab_lines.lines = NULL;
    ntab_lines.max_elements = 0;
    ntab_lines.index = 0;
    node_t *words = NULL;
    int word_counter = 0;

    char *exp_filename = NULL;
    struct Ntab ntab_exp_lines;
    ntab_exp_lines.lines = NULL;
    ntab_lines.max_elements = 0;
    ntab_lines.index = 0;
    node_t *exp_words = NULL;
    int exp_word_counter = 0;

    command_line_input(argc, argv, &filename, &exp_filename);

    read_file_in_array(filename, &ntab_lines);
    store_words(&ntab_lines, &words, &word_counter);

    read_file_in_array(exp_filename, &ntab_exp_lines);
    store_words(&ntab_exp_lines, &exp_words, &exp_word_counter);

    remove_exceptions(&words, &exp_words, &word_counter);


#ifdef DEBUG
    _demo();
#endif

    exit(0);
}

void command_line_input(int argc, char *argv[], char **input_file, char **exp_file){
    if (argc == 2){
        *input_file = argv[1];
        *exp_file = NULL;
    }else if(argc == 4){
        if(strcmp(argv[2],"-e") == 0){
            *exp_file = argv[3];
            *input_file = argv[1];
        }else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-e") == 0){
            *exp_file = argv[2];
            *input_file = argv[3];
        }
    }else if(argc == 1 || argc == 3){
        printf("Need more arguments");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void read_file_in_array(char *filename, struct Ntab *ntab){
    FILE *fptr;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
    while((read = getline(&line, &len, fptr)) != -1){
        add_line(line, ntab);
    }

    fclose(fptr);
}

int add_line(char *line, struct Ntab *ntab){
    struct Lines_and_Words *lp;

    if (ntab->lines == NULL){
        ntab->lines = (Lines_and_Words *)malloc(NINIT * sizeof(Lines_and_Words));
        if (ntab->lines == NULL){
            return -1;
        }
        ntab->max_elements = NINIT;
        ntab->index = 0;
    }else if(ntab->index >= ntab->max_elements){
        lp = (Lines_and_Words *) realloc(ntab->lines, (NGROW * ntab->max_elements) * sizeof(Lines_and_Words));
        if (lp == NULL){
            return -1;
        }
        ntab->max_elements *= NGROW;
        ntab->lines = lp;
    }
    strncpy(ntab->lines[ntab->index].array_lines, line, MAX_LINE_LEN);
    return ntab->index++;
}

void store_words(struct Ntab *ntab, node_t **words, int *word_counter){
    int buff_line_num = 0;
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    const char delim[] = " \n";
    char *token;

    for (int i = 0; i<ntab->index; i++){
        strncpy(buffer, ntab->lines[i].array_lines, MAX_LINE_LEN);
        token = strtok(buffer, delim);
        while (token != NULL){
            node_t *new_p = new_node(token);
            *words = add_end(*words, new_p);
            *word_counter = *word_counter + 1;

            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        buff_line_num++;
    }
}

void remove_exceptions(node_t **words, node_t **exp_words, int *word_counter){
    node_t *curr;
    node_t *curr2;

    for (curr = *words; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next){
        for(curr2 = *exp_words; curr2 != NULL; curr2 = curr2->next){
            if (strcmp(curr->text, curr2->text) == 0){
                *words = remove_item(*words, curr->text);
                *word_counter = *word_counter - 1;
                curr2 = *exp_words;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do *you* think you have defined `remove_item`?

Comment: You've called `remove_item` in your code before you've declared it.

Comment: Add a [mcve]? There is too much irrelevant code; you can make your question clearer by reducing your code to minimum.

Comment: @anatolyg: The offending line of code is about 7 lines from the bottom of the code sample.

Comment: @anatolyg Give him a break. If he doesn't understand such an obvious error, how do you possibly expect him to know which parts of the code are relevant or can be removed?

Comment: By trial and error — that's what I always do. But it doesn't matter now: turned out to be just a typo.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is this line:

```
*words = remove_item(*words, curr->text);
```

Here, you're calling the function `remove_item`, which you haven't declared or defined previously. The compiler is telling you that in previous versions of C this was legal, but this is not supported in modern versions of C. That explains the first error about implicitly-defined functions.

The second issue that's being reported is a type conversion error. In older C versions, a function that was implicitly declared would have its return type assumed to be an `int`. The warning about that `int` conversion is due to the compiler saying "well, I don't see this function, so I'll assume it returns an `int`, but if I do that something else bad happens." Once `remove_item` is made available, this warning should go away.

To fix this, either define this function, prototype this function, or change which function you're calling.